# React redirecting to 404 Route from id-based Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have such Routes. When I type wrong top tree path, like `/homedsf` - it redirects to `NotFoundPage` component like it should. But when I do it in `products` like `/products/dsf`, it just does not open needed product and stays on `products` page. How should I handle these wrong `id`'s?

```
const Main = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path={['/products/:id', '/products']} component={CardList} />
    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contacts} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
);
```

```
const Products = () => <CardList />;
```

```
const CardList = ({ match, history }) => (
  <ul className="card-section">
    {сardData.map((card) => (
      <Card
        key={card.id}
        isSelected={match.params.id === card.id}
        history={history}
        {...card}
      />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

**UPD:** Thanks to Nitin Dev's answer, I implemented it this way:

```
const CardList = ({ match, history }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { id } = match.params;
    const exists = сardData.find(el => el.id === id);
    if (id && !exists) {
      history.push('/404');
    }
  }, [match]);

  return (
    <ul className="card-section">
      {сardData.map(card => (
        <Card
          key={card.id}
          isSelected={match.params.id === card.id}
          history={history}
          {...card}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether you are able to get the route params i.e id, in the component or not.If not try to use the path without array and separate it out.

```js
const Main = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/products/:id" component={ProductComponent} />
    <Route exact path="/products" component={CardList} />
    <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contacts} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
);
```

For handling the wrong product ids you can check in the components whether there is id param is available or not, else redirect wherever you want.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Making separate products did not work, cause my single `Card` instanse is a part or `CardList` and can't be displayed instead if it. But I tried to redirect from `CardList` and it did work. I will accept your answer and update my question.